# iOS 11 Navigationbar icon issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image: How to set Left/Right and title view (OBJC)]

iOS 11 navigation issue i need to set left right and title view on navigation bar

1. This is My current code.
2. So is this, but now i have issue with it:

   ```
     btnMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
     [btnMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
     [btnMenu setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
     [btnMenu setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
     [btnMenu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btnMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(clickOnMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     leftBarButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnMenu];

     [arrLeftBarButton addObject:leftBarButton2];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrLeftBarButton];


   [viewTitle addSubview:search];
   [viewTitle addSubview:btnSelectSearch];
   viewTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

   self.navigationItem.titleView = viewTitle;

   BBBadgeBarButtonItem *badgeNotify = [[BBBadgeBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomUIButton:btnNotify];
   badgeNotify.badgeBGColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   badgeNotify.badgeTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   badgeNotify.badgeValue = @"0";

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = badgeNotify;
   ```

Comment: It seems that you are setting images which are not of recommended size for the navigation bar. Have look at the Human Interface Guidelines : https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/ PS: It will be easier for us if you could post your code. So that actual issue can be pointed out.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442573/navigation-bar-rightbaritem-image-button-bug-ios-11

Answer (score 0):

Obj-C

```
NSLayoutConstraint * widthConstraint = [btnMenu.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:25];
NSLayoutConstraint * heightConstraint =[btnMenu.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:25];
[widthConstraint setActive:YES];
[heightConstraint setActive:YES];

UIBarButtonItem* btnMenuItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: btnMenu];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnMenuItem;
```

Swift

```
 let widthConstraint = button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25)
 let heightConstraint = button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25)
 heightConstraint.isActive = true
 widthConstraint.isActive = true
```