# Xcode 9.0 iOS11 Has Screwed Up Right UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, ios11, xcode9

**older version of xcode (8.3.3)**
[image]

**newer version of Xcode (9.0)**
[image]

Any idea what happened to the hearts+number (favorites) in storyboard? When I run the app, it's also still wrong.

**View Structure**

[image: View Structure]

**Constraints of Favorites Background View**

[image]

Comment: We had the same issue with a left bar button item, we put a `#available(iOS 11.0, *)` check in viewDidLoad and move the button's coordinates to the right place in there.

Comment: You can follow this trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442573/navigation-bar-rightbaritem-image-button-bug-ios-11/46603200#46603200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for us was to use Safe Area Layout Guides and fix any autolayout constraint issues.

As a side note:, we tried changing it from just using the bar to a full UINavigationController approach. That looked promising. However, changing the tintColor status bar didn't work programmatically. So, we had to go back to the bar approach.

Answer (score 1):

You must use Safe Area Layout Guides or add constraint to margins. If this not helps - try add constraint to superview.