# Navigation bar custom image view issue in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I'm setting a normal image view as a custom view for my nav bar item but this is what it's happening:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34))
imageView.kf.setImage(with: user.profilePictureURL)
if user.profilePictureURL == nil {
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ProfilePlaceholderSuit")
}
imageView.backgroundColor = .white
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 17
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
print("ok, so the image view frame is", imageView.frame) // 0, 0, 34, 34
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This types of issue faced by many developers because of in iOS 11 `UIBarButtonItem` uses auto-layout instead of frames.

So you just want to set profile image on top right barButton items then [please check my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442573/navigation-bar-rightbaritem-image-button-bug-ios-11/46603200#46603200).

Other wise you can add constraints of **imageView** in you code like below

```
    let widthConstraint = imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
    let heightConstraint = imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
    heightConstraint.isActive = true
    widthConstraint.isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with the Kingfisher framework. I've switched to SDWebImage and it works fine (sometimes).

Edit:

This worked

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34).isActive = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34).isActive = true
```

Comment: No it's not  problem with the Kingfisher framework, it's issue of iOS 11 your should use autolayout instead of frame

Comment: Thanks @iPatel. Do I have to constraint the image view to the navigation bar or just set its height and width?

Comment: That works @iPatel. feel free to post that as an answer

Comment: But why you using image view and add UITapGestureRecognizer even UIButton provide inbuilt functionality?

Comment: So I could set the image of the image view easily with Kingfisher, but yeah good point.

Comment: By SDWebImage you can also set image of UIButton and you can also follow this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442573/navigation-bar-rightbaritem-image-button-bug-ios-11/46603200#46603200