# Swift 4 iOS 11 navigation bar back button is pushed by a title view with long text

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios11, navigationbar

For a long title on iOS 11, the back button arrow and text are not showing.

I searched for a solution and the closest I got was [navigation bar rightbaritem image-button bug iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456952/429763)

It looks like this
[image: as it looks with a long title]
When it should look like this for long titles also
[image: the back button should show as it does with a short title]
My problem though is that I don't have an explicit button added, instead the titleview pushes the "< Back" default leftBarButtonItem that I create:

`navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Back",  comment: ""), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)`

How can I add constraints to that (UIBarButtonItem)?

Comment: You should be setting constraints on custom views add to `UIToolbar`s (i.e. your `titleView`) There is no way to add constraints directly to a `UIBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up lowering the compression resistance of the titleviews text, so the bar button items have higher priorities and everything fell in place.