# UIToolbar with UIBarButtonItem LayoutConstraint issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, nslayoutconstraint, uitoolbar

I'm creating a UIToolbar with UIBarButtonItem in it programatically. I'm not using .xib or storyboard for this ViewController. Here's the code of how I created it.

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem;
buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: [Language get:@"Home" alter:nil]
                                               style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                              target: self
                                              action: @selector(viewChangeTo)];
[items addObject:buttonItem];

toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 44);
[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Each time the view get loaded I'm getting the LayoutConstraints error.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000023de350 H:|-(20)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fed8c463e00'Home']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fed8c463bb0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000023de3a0 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fed8c463e00'Home']-(20)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fed8c463bb0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000023dff70 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fed8c463bb0.width == 0   (active)>

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-01-21 13:14:24.777354+0800 M[50994:10130357] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000023de530 _UIModernBarButton:0x7fed8c463e00'Home'.lastBaseline == UILayoutGuide:0x6000039eef40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000023de580 V:|-(>=0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fed8c463e00'Home']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fed8c463bb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000023e5680 UIButtonLabel:0x7fed8c457e90'Home'.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x7fed8c463e00'Home'.centerY + 1.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000023e4c80 '_UITemporaryLayoutHeight' _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fed8c463bb0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000023de490 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000039eef40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fed8c463bb0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000023e5680 UIButtonLabel:0x7fed8c457e90'Home'.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x7fed8c463e00'Home'.centerY + 1.5   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463820/ios-11-uibutton-inside-uibarbuttonitem-causes-an-autolayout-error. Personally I consider this an iOS bug.

Comment: I have had exactly the same constraint error when creating the toolbar using `UIToolbar()`, as pointed out above it's an iOS bug. The workaround as suggested by @strohtennis is to use init with CGRect param.

Comment: Not only do you need to set the height of the ToolBar, but it must be higher than each button's height to avoid triggering the warnings...

Answer (score 60):

using swift instead of:
`let toolbar = UIToolbar()`

use:
`let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 35))`

Comment: The above fixed the issue. Seems like the height value when below 12 causing the constraint issue. I now create the UIToolbar using the init with CGRect as you suggested, set the `translateAutoResizingmask` to false and set the layout constraints.

Comment: THX for that comment! I isolated the behavior of warnings vs. height (if a button is taller than the frame's height, the warnings go off..) there's swift sample code in -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682544/uitoolbar-layout-constraints-issue-using-autolayout/76345339#76345339

Answer (score 0):

Using `toolbar.sizeToFit()` won't catch layoutConstraintsIssue unless you set UIToolbar's frame.

This issues happened to me before, and I solved by setting toolbar's frame.