# Navigationbar items not showing on ios 11

Tags: ios, xcode

I am placing profile picture and a button to left of profile picture to right side of the navigation bar. It was working well before the iOS 11 but now they are not showing. How could I fix them?

[image]

I saw this question: [navigation bar rightbaritem image-button bug iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442573/navigation-bar-rightbaritem-image-button-bug-ios-11)

But i think it is not the same problem.

Comment: how is it coming now? please update pic

Comment: @MridulGupta I didn't get you. Can't see any problem with my pic?